# Unable to open the app when clicking on push notification using PhoneGap plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I am able to receive the notification with action button using phonegap plugin. However, I am not able to open the app when I click on notification.

I have checked following parameter in config.xml

android:launchMode="singleTop"

I have tried various payloads. I am using postman to send these notification. I am able to open the app when i use following payload(Supported by FCM) but I don't receive action buttons.

```
{
    "registration_ids": ["dG7v71qgTtQ:APA91bGzfypc_bf-YZ_Gzayqoit4b4DeAZpCaTvPq5Cw3XqTClEFVkgTvvIZCkJVPXIa6-iLnzSrLuFO39SN-kCypBkkxklBIkf4qyYb1WWRZV4qVpR7sMKsNE3tNqtvd6m-ierZxRT6"],
    "notification": {
        "title": "My title",
        "message": "My message."

    },

    "data": {

        "actions": [
            { "title": "Accept", "callback": "app.accept", "foreground": true},
            { "title": "Ignore", "callback": "app.ignore", "foreground": false}
        ]
    }
}
```

When I use following payload I receive action buttons notification. But not able to open the app when user clicks the notification!

```
{
  "registration_ids": ["dG7v71qgTtQ:APA91bGzfypc_bf-YZ_Gzayqoit4b4DeAZpCaTvPq5Cw3XqTClEFVkgTvvIZCkJVPXIa6-iLnzSrLuFO39SN-kCypBkkxklBIkf4qyYb1WWRZV4qVpR7sMKsNE3tNqtvd6m-ierZxRT6"],
  "data": {
    "title": "AUX Scrum",
    "message": "agenda.",
    "actions": [
      {
        "icon": "emailGuests",
        "title": "EMAIL GUESTS",
        "callback": "emailGuests",
        "foreground": true
      },
      {
        "icon": "snooze",
        "title": "SNOOZE",
        "callback": "snooze",
        "foreground": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected result: User should be able to receive action button push notification and  clicking notification opens the app.

Actual Result: User receive action button notification, but on clicking notification, Notification is closed and app is not opened( Even if App is in Foreground or background)

Answer (score 1):

There was a plugin issue. I reinstalled the plugin and it worked.